# .bat within a .bat, not operational -- how would you have done it?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have received a warning that this is a too "subjective" question, but I can't really find another way to say this in a text as short as a title, so my apologies... any suggestions for a title are appreciated.

So on to my question, yesterday I tried to code something and I failed, simple as that... after several hours of searching for the problem, I still couldn't find it: so in hopes of finding a solution, I am asking, how would you have done it?

Goal:

There is a file called a.bat in the F:\ directory, that needs to be moved to the C:\Users directory when clicked upon, and since the act of moving would disrupt the file, it needs to be re-started from the C:\Users directory after the move. So we need to code a batch within a batch, right?

One that would form when a.bat is clicked, and do the move as well as launching a.bat when the move is finished. Now I can't seem to do it, the code just does not work. It creates a loop of CMDs that forces me to restart the computer, even though it seems like a simple task -- and yes I did if %cd% == C:\Users goto z, which would skip creating the batch that would do the move, if the file is already in that directory.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding the question you might try something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: If the script is not running under "C:\Users" it will copy
:: itself there and then execute that copy which will remove
:: this copy (ie. the copy in F:\) and then perform the normal
::script operations.

IF /I NOT "%~dp0"=="C:\Users\" (
  IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\%~nx0" COPY "%~0" C:\Users
  IF EXIST "C:\Users\%~nx0" (
    "C:\Users\%~nx0" "%~0"
    GOTO END
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Unable to copy the script to "C:\Users".
    ECHO.
    ECHO Ensure you are running the script as an administrator and try again.
    ECHO.
    ECHO Press any key to close this window ...
    PAUSE > NUL
    GOTO END
  )
)


:: The first parameter of the script (%~1) is the path to the old
:: location of the script that needs to be removed.  The parameter
:: is used recursively (above) whenever the script is executed from
:: a location other than "C:\Users".

IF NOT "%~1"=="" IF EXIST "%~1" DEL /F "%~1"


::
:: Put your script code here
::

:END
```

**NOTE:**
The batch file will have to run as an admin in order to make a copy in C:\Users unless the permissions of C:\Users have been changed to allow standard users to write to the folder.

Comment: The original question can be found [here](http://superuser.com/q/1131557/573485).

Comment: I looked at it briefly and I think the solution I've suggested here (just updated with more comments and clarification) should work.  Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to move the .bat file.  Just call `cd` to change the directory of the batch instance.  Create a new .bat file with the following contents, and run it from any location.

```
cd C:\Users
dir
pause
```

This file should output the files and directories in C:\Users